# Enum to dropdownlistfor isn't giving me numeric value but giving me text value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty, TEnum>(
                    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
                    TEnum selectedValue)
        {
            IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                                        .Cast<TEnum>(); 
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = from value in values
                                                select new SelectListItem()
                                                {
                                                    Text = value.ToString(),
                                                    Value = value.ToString(),
                                                    Selected = (value.Equals(selectedValue))
                                                }; 
            return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper,expression, items);
        }
```

Now, code above is not mine. It was from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/662968/Creating-a-DropDownList-for-Enums-in-ASP-NET-MVC) it works great. You can use this in view just be adding the namespace in `Web.config` under `Views` folder. But one thing that I cannot solve. The `value` it's giving me is the `Text` Not the numeric one. Say,

```
public enum OrderType
{
  Foo = 1,
  Bar = 2
}
```

Then by using this in a `View`

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.OrderTypeId, Model.OrderType as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>())
```

This gives me:

```
<option value="Foo">Foo</option>
<option value="Bar">Bar</option>
```

I want this one:

```
<option value="1">Foo</option>
<option value="2">Bar</option>
```

**UPDATE**
In the link I provided to where the code came from. It offers two options. 1st one which really works. Giving me numeric value while the second one (the code in my question) doesn't give me numeric value (but still works). Been looking for ways on how to tweak option number 2 since I think it's much cleaner.

What should be done to achieve such result? Many thanks.

Comment: Try `Value = ((int)value).ToString()` (convert to int, then to string)

Comment: Tried that but giving me `Cannot cast expression of type 'TEnum' to type 'int'`

Comment: Try `var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum));` (no cast) with `Value = ((int)value).ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty, TEnum>(
                this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
                TEnum selectedValue)
            where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof (TEnum))
                .Cast<TEnum>().ToArray();

            var items = values
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Text = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Value = Convert.ChangeType(x, x.GetTypeCode()),
                    Selected = (x.Equals(selectedValue))
                })
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.Text,
                Value = x.Value == null
                    ? ""
                    : x.Value.ToString(),
                Selected = x.Selected
            });

            return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items);
        }
```

Comment: 1st `cannot resolve` while the second one giving me `Cannot cast expression of type 'TEnum' to type 'int'`

Comment: @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.OrderTypeId, Model.OrderType as <your enum type>)

Comment: Giving me `is a non-nullable value type` updated my question though.

Comment: Wow! You rock! This actually works. Hope you don't mind explaining what's wrong with the other one (the code that's in my question) for other's reference. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem, your code different from mine this line: Value = Convert.ChangeType(x, x.GetTypeCode()), other just optimize

Comment: This line, what does this do anyway? `Text = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` I noticed this was changed also.

Comment: convert to string with current culture settings

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor` instead of `@Html.DropdownListFor`.

Comment: My bad. That should be `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor` sorry for the typo. But still, giving me text values

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty, TEnum>(
                this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
                TEnum selectedValue)
    {
        IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                                    .Cast<TEnum>(); 
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = from value in values
                                            select new SelectListItem()
                                            {
                                                Text = value.ToString(),
                                                Value = (int)value,
                                                Selected = (value.Equals(selectedValue))
                                            }; 
        return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper,expression, items);
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks but it's giving me `Cannot cast expression of type 'TEnum' to type 'int'`

Comment: It's bad solution, because enum may be no int type